# Ошибка DialogFragment() при использовании AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Класс, в котором находиться метод, с `DialogFragment()` и `AlertDialog.Builder`, который выводит диалоговое окно при окончании игры:

```
//---Класс реализует логику игры и рисует игровые объекты на экране---//
public class CannonView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
...
//---отображение окна AlertDialog при завершении игры
private void showGameOverDialog(final int messageId){

    //---объект DialogFragment для вывода статистики и начала новой игры
    final DialogFragment gameResult = new DialogFragment(){
        @Override
        //---метод создает объект AlertDialog и возвращает его
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {
            //---создание диалогового окна...
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            //---с выводом строки messageId
            builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(messageId));

            //---вывод кол-ва выстрелов и затраченного времени
            builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(
                    R.string.results_format, shotsFired, totalElapsedTime));
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_game, 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                //---вызывается при нажатии кнопки "Reset Game"
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialogIsDisplayed = false;
                    newGame(); //---создание и начало новой игры
                }
            });

            return builder.create(); //---вернуть AlertDialog
        }
    };

//---в UI-потоке FragmentManager используется для вывода DialogFragment
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showSystemBars();  //---выход из полноэкранного режима
            dialogIsDisplayed = true;
            gameResult.setCancelable(false); //---модальное окно
            gameResult.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "results");
        }
    });
}
...
}
```

Начиная с создания диалогового окна: ... *= new DialogFragment(){*... и заканчивая  ...*return builder.create();*... Android Studio реагирует предупреждением об ошибке: *Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static...* и рекомендует использовать: *@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")*. Но хоть с применением рекомендации, хоть без нее приложение не запускается ни на виртуальном, ни на физическом устройствах.

В документации указано, что `DialogFragment()` и `AlertDialog.Builder` нельзя использовать вместе, но у меня, пока, недостаточно знаний для фикса этой проблемы. И может ли этот участок кода быть причиной неработоспособности приложения? Спасибо.

P.S.: данный код взят из книги: Android для разработчиков 3-е издание 2016г.

Авторы: П. Дейтел, Х. Дейтел, А. Уолд

Comment: А какую ошибку выдает кроме вот этого предупреждения?

Comment: LogCat ссылалается на строки с инициализацией звуков, я их закомментировал, игра запустилась но теперь диалоговое окно постоянно висит на экране. Кнопка в диалоговом окне "Reset Game" просто перезапускает это же окно.

Comment: Вполне вероятно, что я мог ошибиться в другом месте. Но мне интересно, пример кода, который в "описании" является допустимым или его лучше избегать, я имею ввиду такую связку DialogFragment() и AlertDialog.Builder?

Comment: Не знаю где вы нашли информацию, что такую связку нельзя использовать. Так всегда строится DialogFragment.
Cам гугл предлагает использовать DialogFragment, потому что вы получаете все преимущества фрагмента. Тогда вы облегчаете жизенный цикл для активити, которая создает такой диалог, а также получаете возомжность переиспользовать этот диалог где-то в другом месте

Comment: Единственный нюанс в этом коде, то что это анонимный класс, вы можете выделить его в обычный класс и переиспользовать

Comment: @ Valgaal Спасибо, Вы немного прояснили ситуацию для меня)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=ru
Пособие от гугла по DialogFragment на русском, на всякий случай.
А ошибка скорей всего где-то в другом месте.

Comment: @ Valgaal Вот в этом же источнике и вычитал, что: ...С помощью класса DialogFragment обеспечивается гибкость решения, поскольку он может вести себя как встраиваемый Fragment.

Тем не менее, в этом случае нельзя использоватьAlertDialog.Builder или другие объекты Dialog для построения диалогового окна....Это, собственно, меня и смутило.